# How to dynamically add and delete view in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design below screen
[image]

When i press 'Add number' button, it will insert one entry in below scrollable layout. In that when i press 'X' button it should delete that particular row.
How to achieve this??
Any idea??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Use a ListView  for displaying the list of patterns
2. Create a custom layout for each list item. e.g.

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="555*" />
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="matched 5 " />       
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="X" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Create a Custom Adapter class extending BaseAdapter

   - It can maintain a list for the patterns to be shown
   - In the getView method of the custom adapter -

     - inflate the xml
     - set the information (like pattern and number of matches) based on the index parameter, using the list
     - set onclick listener for the button (delete that item from list and call notifyDatasetInvalidated())
     - return the view.
4. On "Add Number" add item to the list in the adapter

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ViewGroup.addView(View view);
```

to add a view to some layout.

To create a layout dynamically, use:

```
TextView txtView=new TextView(this);
//Its an example, you can create layouts, buttons, image view, and other components.
```

To Delete a layout or view dynamically, getParent of layout, and delete, by:

```
ViewGroup.removeView(View view);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `ListView` which is backed by an `ArrayList` of `Objects` or `Strings`. When you want to remove an item from your `ListView`, remove the object from the `ArrayList`  :

```
mData.remove(object);
```

and then notify the `ListView` that the date has changed :

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```